# AJAX/JQuery function undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a project that allows users to invite other users.  When a user gets an invite, a pop-up should, well...pop up...asking them to accept or decline.  For this, I'm using an AJAX call to check if they have any invites.  This will eventually be an automatically called function, but for now I'm just testing it with a simple button and onclick function.

What happens is, the AJAX request goes to checkInvitations.php, which checks a database table full of users.  In plain English, checkInvitations.php checks whether the "user" AJAX sent over has an invitation.  If they do, checkInvitations passes information back to the AJAX request with (name of person who invited the user) and (confirmation of an invite).

For whatever reason, though, my function keeps coming up as undefined, even though I've imported the JQuery library.  I've no idea why this is the case.

Here's the function with the AJAX request.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

function checkForInvitations()
{
    var invitedPlayer = '<?php echo $_SESSION["goodUser"]; ?>' //invitedPlayer = the logged-in user
    console.log("invitedPlayer is: "+invitedPlayer); //variable debug check

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "checkInvitations.php",
    data: {invitedPlayer: invitedPlayer},

    success: function(data)
    {
        // parse json string to javascript object
        var invitations = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(invitations); //variable debug check

        // check the invitations to/from
        var invitingPlayer = invitations.invitationFrom;
        var invitationStatus = invitations.invitationStatus;

        //if player has received an invite, pop up a screen asking them to confirm/accept the invite
        if(invitationStatus != 'false')
        {
            clearInterval(checkInvitationIntervalId);
            confirm_yes = confirm(invitingPlayer+" invited you to a game. Accept ?");

        }   
    }
    })
}
```

And here's the PHP page it requests to

```
<?php
session_start();

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'warzone');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$invitations = array();
//look for rows in database where user=the invited user and the invitestatus has been set to true (after invite was sent)
$request = "SELECT * FROM warzone.logged_in_users WHERE USER='".$_POST["invitedPlayer"]."' AND INVITESTATUS='TRUE'";
$res = $conn->query($request);

if($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    $invitations["invitationFrom"]=$row["INVITING_PLAYER"];
    $invitations["invitationStatus"]='true';    
}   
else
{
    $invitations["invitationFrom"]='none';
    $invitations["invitationStatus"]='false';
}

echo json_encode($invitations);

?>
```

Keep in mind when I use the $_SESSION["goodUser"] in place of $_POST["invitedPlayer"] in the above PHP file, I get the exact output I'm looking for.  I know that works.  I just can't get it to work with $_POST, obviously, because the AJAX request isn't being made/is broken/is undefined.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $_SESSION["goodUser"] value transfer to hidden and use hidden value in  javascript.

Comment: what exactly is undefined? can you debug and tell us exactly what value you are missing?  you can see in the network tab if you make a XML request to the file, if you have XML request in network that means the ajax is working.

Comment: add error:  section after the success to see if the call is even been made. Also, you might need to make your data as data:JSON.stringify( {invitedPlayer: invitedPlayer}),

Comment: @codelover I don't think that's the issue, as when I just manually set the invitedPlayer to what I want (in this case, a string with the correct username), it still gives me an undefined function error.

Comment: @Bindrid I know it's not being made because I can't even call the function as-is because it's "undefined."  That's something to think about once I can work around the present error, though.

Comment: @YanMayatskiy there is no XML request in the network tab.  The problem is I'm trying to debug but cannot because the entire function is not defined.  Thought maybe codelover's suggestion was the problem, but it doesn't appear to be the issue.

Comment: Is $ definded?  are you calling the function before all of the includes are loaded?

Comment: @Bindrid not sure what you mean when you ask if $ is defined.

Comment: Did you make sure that all jquery components are fully loaded before calling?   Also, this symptom can also indicate a misplaced quoute, semicolon, etc. Have you check for syntax on the whole page?

Comment: jQuery adds (I believe it's also called namespace) `$` as namespace. Beneath $ you find jQuery functions. e.g. `$.ajax`. You can test whether it's accessable using the developer console by your browser. Simply press F12 to access the dev console. Then go to "console" and type in `$.`. If you receive auto completion it is accessable.

Comment: My guess is that jQuery isn't loaded by the time you're trying to use it. Your jQuery functions should be in a separate script tag (not the one which loads the jQuery library). You might also have to wait for doc ready. See [jQuery basics](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Comment: @Moob THANK YOU.  All I had to do was move my function(s) to a different script tag and it worked instantly.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Mozzila Developer API on script tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

> If a script element has a src attribute specified, it should
>   not have a script embedded inside its tags.

Therefor you want to seperate your inclusion of jquery into a seperate tag.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script> 
<!-- end script before you start the one with your code in it -->
<script type="text/javascrpt">

  // Your code that involves $ here...

</script>
```